# Raw loops vs. algorithm for loops that depend on the index

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on big codes for which performance matters. And one of the things I read is that raw loops should be avoided and replaced by for_each, range-based for loops, or STL algorithms etc etc. The problem is that in all (most) examples, everything looks adapted for the problem, i.e. for_each is shown with the cout routine *eye roll*.

In my case, the index inside the loop matters (unless you show me otherwise). For example, I want to create tables like this:

```
std::vector<double> vect1 (nmax), vect2 (nmax);
for (size_t i{0}; i < nmax; ++i) {
    vect1[i] = f(i);  // f is a routine defined somewhere else
    vect2[i] = f(i)+2.0;
}
```

What I could use is the generate function with a lambda function and it would be something like this:

```
std::vector<double> vect1 (nmax), vect2 (nmax);
size_t count{0};
generate(vect1.begin(), vect1.end(), [&]() {return f(count++);});

count=0;
generate(vect2.begin(), vect2.end(), [&]() {return f(count++) + 2.0;});
```

But I’m not a big fan of that, because:

1. count exists until the end of the routine.
2. We see that with another function, I have to put back count to zero and generate another vector again. I have to track down all the count variables etc. With the for loop, I could just put it in the same loop.
3. With the for loop, the correspondence is seen easily. i is on the left and the right. With generate, I feel like it’s counting with a different variable on the left and the right, which means potential mistake.
4. I can only do count++, not ++count, which means copy of variables.

Of course, this is a simple example. But I would like to know if the generate() version is still better for this kind of things (code/performance/readability wise). Or maybe there’s a better way of doing it, and I’m open to all suggestions and comments.

Thanks!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If you use `++count` the function receives the next index, not the current index.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I thought OP meant that it wouldn't compile.

Comment: As always with performance: measure. That being said, using `for_each` instead of a straight `for` for performance reasons *on a vector* is generally misguided. For other containers where random item access is slower than incrementing an iterator, it may make sense (but in that case, range based for is equivalent and more readable).

Comment: Calling `f(i)` twice (assuming it's a pure-ish function) is probably a far bigger issue performance wise

Comment: I certainly agree that there are times that for_each, etc, don't describe your problem very well. If they don't then perhaps they aren't the right mechanism to use. In this particular case, reserve and push_back() would seem the correct mechanism, anyway???

Comment: "And one of the things I read is that raw loops should be avoided and replaced by for_each, range-based for loops, or STL algorithms etc etc." you read wrong source.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an `index` range that lets me:

```
std::vector<double> vect1 (nmax), vect2 (nmax);
for (auto i : index_upto(nmax))
  vect1[i] = f(i);  // f is a routine defined somewhere else
  vect2[i] = f(i)+2.0;
}
```

which eliminates the manual fenceposting but leaves the code otherwise unchanged.

This isn't all that hard.  Write a pseudo-iterator that stores a T and returns a copy on unary `*`.  It should support `==` and `++` (passing both into the stored `T`).

```
template<class T>
struct index_it {
  T t;
  index_it& operator++() { ++t; return *this; }
  index_it operator++(int) { auto r = *this; ++*this; return r; }
  friend bool operator==( index_it const& lhs, index_it const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.t == rhs.t;
  }
  friend bool operator!=( index_it const& lhs, index_it const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.t != rhs.t;
  }
  T operator*()const& { return t; }
  T operator*()&& { return std::move(t); }
};
```

Next, write a range:

```
template<class It>
struct range {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
};
```

then compose the two.

```
template<class T>
using index_range = range<index_it<T>>;

template<class T>
index_range<T> make_index_range( T s, T f ) {
  return {{std::move(s)}, {std::move(f)}};
}

index_range<std::size_t> index_upto( std::size_t n ) {
  return make_index_range( std::size_t(0), n );
}
```

note that `index_it` is *not* an iterator, but works much like one.  You could probably finish it and make it an input iterator; beyond that you run into problems as iterators expect backing containers.

Comment: Join our quest to turn c++ into python... :-)

Comment: @JiveDadson It cannot be a random access container, because the iterators cannot be random-access iterators, because random access iterators are forward iterators, and forward iterators `operator*` **must** return an actual reference, and that reference must persist beyond the lifetime of the iterator in question (ie, must cannot be a reference to a member of the iterator, nor can ++ edit its value).  You can claim it is a random access iterator and 95% of code works with it, and 5% breaks horribly, and all use of it in `std` makes your program ill-formed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm learning a lot by just reading your code. But apart from making the code more readable, do we gain performance doing it?

Comment: @yann no, unless the code before was badly written.  The maon advantage is safety; not accidentally messing with indexing in loop body.

Answer (score 1):

We could use a mutable lambda...

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

double f(int x) { return x*2; }

int main()
{
    constexpr int nmax = 100;
    std::vector<double> vect1 (nmax), vect2 (nmax);

    std::generate(vect1.begin(), 
                  vect1.end(), 
                  [count = int(0)]() mutable { return f(count++); });

    std::generate(vect2.begin(), 
                  vect2.end(), 
                  [count = int(0)]() mutable { return f(count++) + 2.0; });

}
```

Another option (uses c++17 for template argument deduction):

```
template<class F>
struct counted_function
{
    constexpr counted_function(F f, int start = 0, int step = 1) 
    : f(f)
    , counter(start)
    , step(step) {}

    decltype(auto) operator()() {
        return f(counter++);
    }

    F f;
    int counter;
    int step;
};
```

used as:

```
std::generate(vect2.begin(), 
              vect2.end(), 
              counted_function([](auto x) { return f(x) + 2.0; }));
```

And finally, just for fun, could write this:

```
generate(vect2).invoking(f).with(every<int>::from(0).to(nmax - 1));
```

...if we had written something like this...

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

double f(int x) { return x*2; }

template<class T> struct value_iter
{
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = T;
    using reference = T&;
    using pointer = T*;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    friend bool operator==(value_iter l, value_iter r)
    {
        return l.current == r.current;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(value_iter l, value_iter r)
    {
        return !(l == r);
    }

    T const& operator*() const& { return current; }
    value_iter& operator++() { ++current; return *this; }

    T current;
};

template<class T> struct every
{
    struct from_thing
    {
        T from;

        struct to_thing
        {
            auto begin() const { return value_iter<T> { from };}
            auto end() const { return value_iter<T> { to+1 };}
            T from, to;
        };

        auto to(T x) { return to_thing { from, x }; }
    };

    static constexpr auto from(T start)
    {
        return from_thing { start };
    }

};

template<class F>
struct counted_function
{
    constexpr counted_function(F f, int start = 0, int step = 1) 
    : f(f)
    , counter(start)
    , step(step) {}

    decltype(auto) operator()() {
        return f(counter++);
    }

    F f;
    int counter;
    int step;
};

template <class Container> struct generate
{
    generate(Container& c) : c(c) {}

    template<class F>
    struct invoking_thing
    {

        template<class Thing>
        auto with(Thing thing)
        {
            using std::begin;
            using std::end;
            std::copy(begin(thing), end(thing), begin(c));
            return c;
        }

        F f;
        Container& c;
    };

    template<class F>
    auto invoking(F f) { return invoking_thing<F>{f, c}; }

    Container& c;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int nmax = 100;
    std::vector<double> vect2 (nmax);

    generate(vect2).invoking(f).with(every<int>::from(0).to(nmax - 1));
}
```

Comment: I found myself wanting this enough that I wrote a `generate_from_index` function which did that for me

Answer (score 1):

Using a stateful lambda is not a good idea. You may be better off writing your own `generate` function that takes a function object receiving an iterator:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class Generator>
void generate_iter(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Generator g) {
    while (first != last) {
        *first = g(first);
        ++first;
    }
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
generate_iter(vect1.begin(), vect1.end(), [&](const std::vector<double>::iterator& iter) {
    auto count = std::distance(vect1.begin(), iter);
    return f(count);
});
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/kvh2il)

Comment: What's wrong with using a stateful lambda? Just make your own `generate_from_index` that calls `std::generate` with a mutable lambda, wrapping a non-mutable lambda, and you're good

Comment: @Justin Writers of stateful lambdas must make an assumption about the use of the lambda. `std::generate` happens to make a guarantee about the number of times the function is going to be called, but this guarantee becomes embedded in the logic of your function. In this respect "pure" functions are easier to deal with.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Isn't it a guarantee that std algorithms take their functions and predicates by value? This mitigates the risk of lambda abuse somewhat.

Comment: @RichardHodges I believe you're right on that. Standard C++ library is pretty safe with respect to its use of lambdas.

Comment: Thank you! That's actually a really good point. However wouldn't your code be slower then, with all the computation of the distances?

Answer (score 0):

With range-v3, it would be something like:

```
auto vect1 = ranges::view::ints(0, nmax) | ranges::view::transform(f);
auto vect2 = ranges::view::ints(0, nmax) | ranges::view::transform(f2);
// or auto vect2 = vect1 | ranges::view::transform([](double d){ return d + 2.; });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c3de3853ad5bc5a)